# Have svn automatically detect your user credentials?

Tags: svn

Is there a way to have svn automatically detect your credentials (say by reading a .file in your home directory)?

I have a bash script that includes some svn commands, and I want it to automagically run as the user who is running the script. If I put one user's credentials inside the script then it is easier to run (runs easily without questions) but then we don't know who did what?

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using? svn? svn+ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the environment variables in your shell usually provide a USER or UID variable. USER is the current user's username, and UID is the current user's numeric user id.
For example: 'echo $USER'

alternatively you could use the 'id' program, like so: 'id -nu'

I don't think svn can automatically detect the current user's name, but since you're using a bash script you can just supply the name yourself, e.g.: 'svn --username $USER '

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use any authentication at all (e.g. via file://-protocol), Subversion will use your loginname as commitname